# SKLabelNode drawing behind SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

Why does my SKLabelNode always draw behind my SKSpriteNode even though I'm adding it after the sprite?

```
    _startButton = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"start@2x.png"];
    _startButton.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2,self.frame.size.height/2);
    _startButton.name = @"start";
    _startButton.zPosition = 1.0;
    [self addChild:_startButton];

    SKLabelNode *start = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Chalkduster"];
    start.text = @"Start";
    start.fontSize = 40;
    start.fontColor = [SKColor whiteColor];
    start.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2);
    [self addChild:start];
```

Comment: Sprite Kit don't work that way, you should manage your nodes positions with zPosition, _startButton.zPosition = 1; start zPosition = 2; that should work.

Comment: No, zPosition is not required. If you leave zPosition at the default (0) respectively use the same zPosition value for multiple nodes then the order in the children array takes effect for nodes with the same zPosition value (and the same parent).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am pretty sure that the default zPosition is 0 which means that your sprite (with a zPosition of 1) will appear in front of the label. Try setting the `SKLabelNode` zPosition to 2. Larger positive numbers place items on top of those with smaller numbers.

> The default value is 0.0. The positive z axis is projected toward the
>   viewer so that nodes with larger z values are closer to the viewer.
>   When a node tree is rendered, the height of each node (in absolute
>   coordinates) is calculated and then all nodes in the tree are rendered
>   from smallest z value to largest z value. If multiple nodes share the
>   same z position, those nodes are sorted so that parent nodes are drawn
>   before their children, and siblings are rendered in the order that
>   they appear in their parent’s children array. Hit-testing is processed
>   in the opposite order.